# Sortable ul/li tree with move to parent/child and handle

Tags: javascript, sorting, plugins

Hey, i need a lib or a plugin to sort a ul/li tree. It should have the handle option, like the on for jQuery UI. And you should be able to move the li's to the parent or child ul's.

Comment: What's wrong with the one in jQuery UI (http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/)?

Comment: you cant change the depth of the child li's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok ive made this plugin myself, maybe some can use it too.

http://github.com/antpaw/mootools-naviAdmin